# ESM MODULE importing with await issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I'm trying to import in an ESM module with await but when I use the await I don't get any error but the program stops running

```
import { predMaintModel } from "../dataBases/index.js";
import predMaint from "../predMaintenance/index.js";

await predMaint()

const getDeviceData = async (req:any, res:any, cont:any) => {
    const { record, currentAdmin } = cont;

    //  const deviceData = devices.find(device=> device.id === req.params.recordId);

    return {
        record: record.toJSON(currentAdmin),
        // deviceData
    };
};

const getAvailableDevices = async (req:any, res:any, cont:any) => {
    const { record, currentAdmin } = cont;
    const devices = await predMaintModel.find({}, { temperature:0,vibration:0 } )

    return {
        devices
    };
};
export default {
    getDeviceData,
    getAvailableDevices
};
```

I'm expecting to not get promise from my import, I actually have the same structure on other part of my code and it works there.

Comment: `await predMaint()`  top level await in modules, does that even exist?

Comment: apparently not, that was my first thought too

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Keith In a Node context, yes. And at [the top level of modules in modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await_top_level).

Comment: However, OP, you're not "importing with await"; you're importing a function, then awaiting a function call. "importing with await" brings to mind a dynamic import, like `const module = await import('path/to/module.js');` which carries its own set of issues.

Comment: So, what does `predMaint` do?